# Smoothness of signed distance function to a hypersurface

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a Riemannian submanifold and $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{M}$ be a $C^1$ submanifold. Near $\Sigma$, let $d(x)=\pm d(x, \Sigma)$ be the signed distance function to $\Sigma$. Then what can we say about the smoothness of $d$ near $\Sigma$? If $\Sigma$ is a $C^{k,\alpha}$ submanifold, is $d$ also $C^{k,\alpha}$?  In Euclidean space, we know that if $\Sigma$ is $C^k$,$k \ge 2$. Then $d$ is also $C^k$ near $\Sigma$. Is this correct in Riemannian manifolds?

Comment: In Chapter 6 of Lee's Riemannian Manifolds book, he proves that $d$ is $C^\infty$ near $\Sigma$ under the assumption that $\Sigma$ is $C^\infty$. (Theorem 6.40) Perhaps the proof can be generalised.